# Ubuntu 15.10 full freeze (maybe intel hd graphics kernel failure)

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics

my new Acer ES1-411 won't work under Ubuntu... It has a Intel N3540 CPU and a integrated Intel HD Graphics GPU. It has a UEFI and I ran dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10. Under Windows no problems, but I prefer Ubuntu... While just working and surfing it runs, but when I look at videos (mp4) it takes sometimes only seconds sometimes minutes until the machine full freezes, no keyboard and no ssh access to it. So also no logfiles from the crashes exist. I still tried to change the GPU frequency with intel_gpu_frequency from the lowest to highest value, already switched off bluetooth, but no change... I also still tried the latest evaluation version of Ubuntu with the 4.3 kernel and the 01.org intel drivers but also no change. Does anybody know what to do? I think more people have those freezing problem, is there a programmer who wants to find out and fix this for the next version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Investigating a system "freeze"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48029/investigating-a-system-freeze)

Answer (score 2):

I have an issue that sounds pretty similar also on an N3540 CPU. I'm pretty sure this kernel bug may be the culprit, as the identified workaround fixed the problem for me.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

Looks like it has something to do with the Baytrail CPUs changing to a different c-state (idle power state). The consensus seems to be that a workaround is limiting the c-state to a max of 1 by setting the kernel parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`. Presumably, with a cost of less power savings when your machine is idle.

Instructions for setting kernel parameters:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters